# Performing Subquery using Query Builder in Dataset C#

Tags: c#, mysql, rdlc, query-builder

I'm using this sql statement to produce the desired result. And would like to display those result query in my report in C# using rdlc via Dataset(.xsd).

```
SELECT pay.Cutoff, 
       emp.Id, 
       emp.LastName, 
       emp.FirstName, 
       emp.MiddleName, 
       emp.TinNumber, 
       job.Rate * 25 AS FixBIR,

       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS MonthsWorked 
       FROM payroll AS pay3
       WHERE YEAR(pay3.DateGenerated) = 2014
             AND pay3.EmployeeId = 1 
             AND pay3.Cutoff = 1
       ORDER BY MONTH(pay3.DateGenerated) ASC) * (job.Rate * 25)  
       AS MonthsWorked_FixBIR_TODATE,

       pay.TaxWithheld,

       (SELECT SUM(payroll2.TaxWithheld) AS TaxTotal
       FROM employee AS employee2 
       INNER JOIN payroll AS payroll2 
       ON employee2.Id = payroll2.EmployeeId
       WHERE (payroll2.Cutoff = 1) 
       AND (employee2.Id = emp.Id) 
       AND YEAR(payroll2.DateGenerated) = 2014) 
       AS Tax_TODATE,

       YEAR(pay.DateGenerated) AS YEAR

FROM employee AS emp 
INNER JOIN payroll AS pay 
ON emp.Id = pay.EmployeeId
INNER JOIN job 
ON emp.JobId = job.Id
WHERE pay.Cutoff = 1 
AND pay.PayrollMonth = 'August' 
AND Year(pay.DateGenerated) = 2014
```

This statement works fine (tested in navicat).

However, when I transferred this to Dataset using Query Builder it doesn't work. The error says:

**The wizard detects the following  problems when configuring the TableAdapter: "Fill" Details:**

**!Generated SELECT statement
 Error in SELECT clause: expression near 'SELECT'
 Error in SELECT clause: expression near 'FROM'
 Missing FROM Clause
 Error in SELECT clause: expression near ','.
 Unable to parse query text**

And if I try to use a simple subquery in the SELECT statement, an error says:

**The query cannot be represented graphically in the Diagram and Criteria Pane.**

What do I do for me to use the sql statement in rdlc? Are there other ways aside from query builder in dataset?

Comment: try to make your snippet a bit smaller, e.g. select of only 1 or 2 values that cause problems

Comment: How about this one?

`SELECT emp.FirstName, 

(SELECT COUNT(*) AS MonthsWorked 
       FROM payroll AS pay3
       WHERE YEAR(pay3.DateGenerated) = 2014
       ORDER BY MONTH(pay3.DateGenerated) ASC) AS MonthCount

FROM employee emp INNER JOIN payroll pay
ON emp.Id = pay.EmployeeId
WHERE pay.Cutoff = 2`

using subquery in select statement in Query builder prompts an error